# Installing PyAudio gets error: portaudio.h file not found

Tags: python-3.x, speech-recognition, pyaudio, portaudio

I am trying to use the SpeechRecognition library, but I get the error PyAudio not installed. I did `pip3 install PyAudio`, but I get the error `portaudio.h file not found`. I have tried everything. Downloading the .whl file, installing Visual C++ Build Tools and tried installing through pipwin. Can anyone help me?

Comment: i guess wheel file should work what error are you getting when installing wheel file

Comment: I get no error installing the wheel, but when I try to use the SpeechRecognition, it can't find PyAudio.

Comment: can you update the post and show error traceback

Comment: It says: `AttributeError: Could not find PyAudio; check installation`

Comment: create a separate environment and install speech-recognition and pyaudio (with wheel file) and use that environment